# HackerRank Dynamic Array Problem - Runtime Error in the code

Tags: python, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to solve this [Dynamic Array problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array/problem?isFullScreen=true) on HackerRank. This is my code:

```py
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#
# Complete the 'dynamicArray' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER_ARRAY.
# The function accepts following parameters:
#  1. INTEGER n
#  2. 2D_INTEGER_ARRAY queries
#

def dynamicArray(n, queries):
    lastAnswer = 0
    a = []
    array_result = []
    for k in range(n):
        a.append([])
    
    for i in queries:
        x = i[1]
        y = i[2]
        if i[0] == 1:
            seq = ((x ^ lastAnswer) % n)
            a[seq].append(y)
        elif i[0] == 2:
            seq = ((x ^ lastAnswer) % n)
            lastAnswer = a[seq][y]
            array_result.append(lastAnswer)
    return array_result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    first_multiple_input = input().rstrip().split()

    n = int(first_multiple_input[0])
    q = int(first_multiple_input[1])

    queries = [] # 1 0 5, 1 1 7, 1 0 3, ...

    for _ in range(q):
        queries.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

    result = dynamicArray(n, queries)

    fptr.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

I am getting a runtime error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "Solution.py", line 50, in
>
> fptr.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Can anyone help me with this, I can't seem to find a solution.

This is the input:

> 2 5
>
> 1 0 5
>
> 1 1 7
>
> 1 0 3
>
> 2 1 0
>
> 2 1 1

Thanks.

> Update: It seems like this input is working now, thanks to @cireo but the code is not working for other test cases. What the problem with this code?

Comment: It looks like the result of `map(str, result)` is a `NoneType` which is not an iterable as is required by `join()`

Comment: @Dodge thanks. May I know how can I output the values of lastAnswer coz returning that alone is not working.

Comment: As mentioned below, the usual process is not to edit questions in a chained fashion, as it makes the old answers not make sense anymore =).  If you are still stuck after playing with the problem some more (check the hackerrank forums as well), then try to figure out the minimal reproducible problem and ask another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## you can try this, it works totally fine.(no runtime error)

> Replace your dynamicArray function with this code. Hopefully this will be helpful for you (^_^).

def dynamicArray(n, queries):

```
col = [[] for i in range(n)]
res = []
lastanswer = 0
for q in queries:
    data = (q[1]^lastanswer)%n
    if q[0] == 1:
        col[data].append(q[2])
    elif q[0] == 2:
        ind_x = q[2]%len(col[data])
        lastanswer = col[data][ind_x]
        res.append(lastanswer)
return res
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question lies in the boilerplate provided by hackerrank.

`# The function is expected to return an INTEGER_ARRAY.`

You can also see that `result = dynamicArray(n, queries)` is expected to return a list of integers from `map(str, result)`, which throws the exception.

In your code you do `print(lastAnswer)`, but you probably want

```
+ ret = []
    ...
-     print(lastAnswer)
+     ret.append(lastAnswer)
+ return ret
```

instead.

Since you do not return anything, the function returns `None` by default, which cannot be iterated over by `map`.

Comment: Thanks!!! Wow, careless mistake!! I corrected the code but seems like this is not working for other test cases.

Comment: Yeah, you may need another SO question if you get stuck on the actual problem after tinkering with it =)

Answer (score 0):

```
def dynamicArray(n, queries):
# Write your code here
arr=[[]for i in range(0,n)]
lastAnswer=0
answers=[]    
for query in queries:
    if query[0]==1:
        idx= (query[1]^lastAnswer)%n
        arr[idx].append(query[2])
    if query[0]==2:
        idx= (query[1]^lastAnswer)%n
        lastAnswer= arr[idx][query[2]% len(arr[idx])]
        answers.append(lastAnswer)
return answers
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code in js

```
function dynamicArray(n, queries) {

let arr = [];

for (let x = 0; x<n; x++) {
    arr.push([]);
}

let lastAns = 0;

let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
    
    let idx = (queries[i][1] ^ lastAns) % n;
    if (queries[i][0] == 1) {
        arr[idx].push(queries[i][2]);
    } else {
        lastAns = arr[idx][queries[i][2] % arr[idx].length]
        result.push(lastAns);
    }
    
}
return result
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:python], so why did you provide a Javascript solution? This does not answer the OP question about errors in their Python code. Further, code-only answers are rarely useful answers, and certainly not in this case.